# HP pavilion x360 "11 Realtek RTL8723BE weak wifi signal

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I installed Ubuntu 17.10.1 on my HP Pavilion x360 convertible,
and my wi-fi connection was very weak.

I tried to install this driver from GitHub called `rock.new_btcoex`, but it didn't work.

What else can I try?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

Quite often, the weak signal is a symptom of the antenna wire being connected to connection #1 on the card when the default driver is expecting to see the signal at connection #2. Of course, you could open the laptop and switch the wire or you could add a driver parameter that permits antenna selection at the driver level.

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

If this is ineffective, repeat the process with `ant_sel=1`. Reboot.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work
when i use Windows OS the Wi-fi was good but after i install Ubuntu desktop OS the Wi-fi comes weak

Comment: May we see: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` Did you try both =1 and =2?

Comment: yes i try both but it does't work

Comment: Failure to provide requested information is rarely a good strategy when seeking assistance. Please [edit] your post to include the output of  `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` as requested [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002504/hp-pavilion-x360-11-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal#comment1622307_1002529) Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1