# Wifi does not detect all available Wifi in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

SOLUTION:

As the user Chili555 noted in the comments, I did what was said in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002504/hp-pavilion-x360-11-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/1002529#1002529):

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

and it worked when rebooting

---

Original post:

First of all, I am very new to Ubuntu, so please ask for more data if it is needed.

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a dual boot with Windows 10.

I tried connecting to Wifi, but only some appear. For example, I can perfectly connect to my mobile hotspot, but my home wifi is not even listed with the available ones.

I tried many methods found online, but none seemed to work, si I write this question.

Firtly, after making sure drivers were installed, I tried restarting the nerwork-manager by typing:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But this did not work at all, so I tried the fix to stop the mac address changes, changing

```
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

in the file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

However, this also did not work.

I ran lspci and it returned the following:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev 83)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

so I knew my network controller was RTL8723BE. I the added

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="RTL8723BE"
```

to the file /etc/pm/config.d/config (I found this solution online, as well.)

The last step I've tried is to type

```
iw reg get
```

It returned:

```
country ES: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

and then I typed

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

it returned

```
# Set REGDOMAIN to a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code so that iw(8) may set
# the initial regulatory domain setting for IEEE 802.11 devices which operate
# on this system.
#
# Governments assert the right to regulate usage of radio spectrum within
# their respective territories so make sure you select a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2
# country code suitable for your location or you may infringe on local
# legislature. See `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' for a table of timezone
# descriptions containing ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country codes.

REGDOMAIN=
```

As the last line seemed incompleted, I edited at the end

```
REGDOMAIN=ES
```

I rebooted, but it still does not work. At this point I am pretty desperate, because I can't seem to find any solution, and because I know my hardware is working (I can connect to other Wifis) and the network works (I can connect using Windows in the same PC)

Note: if any further information is needed, please let me know so I can add it

Comment: Did you try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002504/hp-pavilion-x360-11-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/1002529#1002529

Comment: No, I have not. Let me try and I will tell you if it works

Comment: @chili555 that helped. Thank you very much. I will edit my question to add this solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your computer is able to detect all WIFI networks in Windows 10.
If yes, then there is no issue with your WLAN hardware.
In this case, what you can do is try reinstalling network-manager applet or user some other network applets. If it still doesn't work, try removing all changes you made to the default config and try once again.
If nothing works, you can try reinstalling the system as well, given that you've just installed the same