# Wifi issues with Ubuntu 14.04 on Realtek

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, realtek

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with realtek rtl8723be wifi driver. The internet on my systems fluctuates constantly. It goes from very high speed to the point where even google homepage takes a lot of time to load.

I have tried other solutions like installing rtl_wifi_new as mentioned in this solution: [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) and a few others. Nothing seems to work.

The internet speed gets back to normal after rebooting.

Help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the link to the results of wireless info script: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MB5b8gWMyX/

Comment: Did you try the `ant_sel` step? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002504/hp-pavilion-x360-11-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal/1002529#1002529 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't help.

Comment: May we please take a look at a full diagnostic? https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Here is the link to the full diagnostic: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ynFTvjZTNF/

Comment: You posted the script itself, not the report that is produced by running the script. Please try again.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Here is the report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MB5b8gWMyX/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77942/discussion-between-codelyzer-and-chili555).

Comment: You would probably be able to restore internet speed by just restarting network manager instead rebooting all the time. You can do that by running `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless info says that the router is on channel 9. I doubt that you set the channel intentionally to 9 as it is an overlapped channel: https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11.html That suggests to me that the router is set to auto channel select, a very bad idea. Please see: https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection

I suggest that you will have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection.

If you did not have administrative privileges for the router, I’d recommend that you speak to the person that does, show them the superuser link I gave and ask them to instead use a fixed channel.

Also, in your scan results, we see Quality=42/70. You’ve indicated that you tried the `ant_sel` parameter available for your driver and I suggest that you now try  =2 if you now have =1 (or vice-versa) to see if the signal quality improves.

In our chat, after trying these steps, you confirmed that everything is working well.